# book index, how to look at each word and store it according to its first letter

Tags: c++, indexing, char

I am trying to read from a file and make an index of all the words in the file to be sent to an array that corresponds to their first letter

for example 
**my input file is something like**

[1]
hi bob
[2]
how are you

**my output should be**

[A]
are, 2
[B]
bob, 1
[H]
hi, 1
how, 2
[Y]
you, 2

I made an array a[10] - z[10] that would store all words that start with 'A' - 'Z'
I am stuck in how to check the first character of the word and then check if it belongs in array of ABC..etc and then put page number.

void Parser::checkWord(){

```
if(buffer == 'a'){
    word<<a[];
}
if(buffer == 'b'){
    word<<b[];
}
if(buffer == 'c'){
    word<<c[];
}
if(buffer == 'd'){
    word<<d[];
}
if(buffer == 'e'){
    word<<e[];
}
if(x == 'f'){
    word<<f[];
}
if(x == 'g'){
    word<<g[];
}
if(buffer == 'h'){
    word<<h[];
}
if(buffer == 'i'){
    word<<i[];
}
if(buffer == 'j'){
    word<<j[];
}
if(buffer == 'k'){
    word<<k[];
}
if(buffer == 'l'){
    word<<l[];
}
if(buffer == 'm'){
    word<<m[];
}
if(buffer == 'n'){
    word<<n[];
}
if(buffer == 'o'){
    word<<o[];
}
if(buffer == 'p'){
    word<<p[];
}
if(buffer == 'q'){
    word<<q[];
}
if(buffer == 'r'){
    word<<r[];
}
if(buffer == 's'){
    word<<s[];
}
if(buffer == 't'){
    word<<t[];
}
if(buffer == 'u'){
    word<<u[];
}
if(buffer == 'v'){
    word<<v[];
}
if(buffer == 'w'){
    word<<w[];
}
if(buffer == 'x'){
    word<<x[];
}
if(buffer == 'y'){
    word<<y[];
}
if(buffer == 'z'){
    word<<z[];
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use an array.  Use `std::vector` or `std::list` instead.

Comment: You may want to use `std::map<char, std::vector<std::string> >`.  This will allow you to do `word << word_map[j]`;

Comment: By the way, you will have to print each word in an array, one at a time, using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution for the second part of your problem. How to maintain your index and produce some output for it. The first part, I am sure is handled in other answers.

Once you have read your word from the file and you know the page you are on, all you have to do is call `UpdateIndex(...)` as shown in the code below. When you are done reading, call `PrintIndex()` to produce your output.

In UpdateIndex, you can also see, how to access the first character of your word.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<uint32_t> PageList;
typedef std::map<std::string,PageList > WordToPageMap;
typedef std::map<char,WordToPageMap > IndexMap;

void UpdateIndex( IndexMap& indexMap, const char * word, uint32_t page )
{
    if( strlen(word) > 0 )
    {
        indexMap[word[0]][word].push_back(page);
    }
}

void PrintIndex( const IndexMap& indexMap )
{
    for( auto& alpha : indexMap )
    {
        std::cout << "[" << alpha.first << "] ";
        for( auto& word : alpha.second )
        {
            std::cout << word.first << " ";
            for( auto& page : word.second )
            {
                std::cout << page << ",";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void TestIndexStuff()
{
    IndexMap indexMap;
    UpdateIndex( indexMap, "hi", 1 );
    UpdateIndex( indexMap, "bob", 1 );
    UpdateIndex( indexMap, "how", 2 );
    UpdateIndex( indexMap, "are", 2 );
    UpdateIndex( indexMap, "you", 2 );
    PrintIndex( indexMap );
}


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    TestIndexStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

Running this, produces output like this:

```
 ./a.out
 [a] are 2,
 [b] bob 1,
 [h] hi 1,how 2,
 [y] you 2,
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break up your input into words using regex.  Then keep an eye on the page number using a variable that you increment each time the word is actually a page number.
Use substring to chop the first letter off each actual word.
You have 3 pieces of data to store each time, would it be easier to put these in a datatable with 3 columns? FirstLetter, PageNo and Word.
Then when you've read the whole file you can sort the datatable by FirstLetter, PageNo and iterate through to produce your output.